# verify a PHP variable and get result from it

Tags: php, javascript, html

Here is my code:-

```
<?php
$URL = "http://www.mylink.com/show_album/XXXXX";
/*The value of $URL will be passed from previous page via Form*/
?>
```

First, The value of the variable must be a link/URL. If not, `echo "Not an URL";` should be executed. But, I am unable to check if it's a link or not. Please, anyone help me to figure out this. As a newbie, I need help badly.

Second, The **http://** is optional. If provided, it's okay. Else, "http://" will be added automatically. I used this code for this and it works.

```
if(strpos($URL, "http://") !== false){
    echo $URL;
    echo "<br />http:// already provided";
    return $URL;
}
else {
    echo "http://" . $URL;
    $URL = "http://" . $URL;
    echo "<br />http:// automatically added";
    return $URL;
}
```

Third, The text "**mylink.com/show_album/**" (without quote) must be available in $URL. I used this code for this:-

```
if (strpos($URL, "mylink.com/show_album/") !== false){
    echo "The "mylink.com/show_album/ is available";
}
else {
    echo "The "mylink.com/show_album/ is not available";
}
```

It's okay.

Next, In the $URL, the value is a link name with a last word XXXXX. It must be the last word of this variable. XXXXX is a number. It can be any number like "12345" or any other. But, I want to get the Number from this $URL and show it. How can I do this?

At last, The link can only contain http:// and www.mylink.com/show_album/XXXXX . Otherwise, the `echo "Not a valid link";` will be executed. How to do this?

Comment: you need to learn about "regular expressions"

Comment: have you tried anything at all?  looks like you kind of know what you're doing,  but don't know how to check if the last X amount of characters are actually numbers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Validating URLs:

```
  $text = preg_replace("
  #((http|https|ftp)://(\S*?\.\S*?))(\s|\;|\)|\]|\[|\{|\}|,|\"|'|:|\<|$|\.\s)#ie",
  "'<a href=\"$1\" target=\"_blank\">$3</a>$4'",
  $text
);
```

For validating/appending http:// on front of URL, do something like:

```
$protocol = substr($URL, 0, 7);
if($protocol!="http://")
{
     $URL="http://".$URL;
}
```

**EDIT**
Now for fetching the last numbers:

```
$XXXXX=substr( $URL, strrpos( $url, '/' )+1 );
```

Comment: But, I need something more.
The XXXXX is not a word of only 5 numbers. The XXXXX should be contain any amount of numbers. Now what can I do for this?

Comment: Well. But, how to use the first code? I am unable to use it. How can I valid an URL using this code?